# Conversão de projeto de Objective-c para Swift (Chamada do servidor)

Tags: ios, web-service, swift

Estou com um problema que passo a explicar, penso que achei uma maneira para chamar os métodos que estão no servidor, no entanto quando chamo um método que tem parâmetros, obtenho um erro, e quando chamo um método que não tem parâmetros corre tudo bem. Alguém me consegue explicar o porque disto acontecer ou o que estou a fazer mal?

Código de chamada do serviço

```
statusCode should be 200, but is 500
resposta do servidor ******** = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fc90a626350> { URL: https://*****.*****.com/****.slet request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://*****.*****.com/****.svc/rest/ListRules")!)  
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "ID=10"    
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("resposta do servidor ******** = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("responseString ++++++++++++ = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()
```

O erro que obtenho é o seguinte:

```
vc/rest/ListRules} { status code: 500, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 1937;
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 27 Jan 2016 10:39:58 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} })
responseString ++++++++++++ = Optional(<Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none"><Code>
<Value>Receiver</Value><Subcode><Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</Value></Subcode></Code>
<Reason><Text xml:lang="en-US">The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. 
This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.</Text></Reason><Detail>
<ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><HelpLink i:nil="true"/><InnerException i:nil="true"/>
<Message>The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding.
See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace><Type>System.InvalidOperationException</Type></ExceptionDetail></Detail></Fault>)
```

Código que me vai resolver o problema no entanto estou a ter um erro ao passar o parâmetro da função

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://*******.*******.com/******.***/***/METODO")!) request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
var postString:NSString = "ID=23"  //--> ERRO?
```

request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

e o erro é "Encountered unexpect charater 'I'" e este i é o do parametro ID, alguem me consegue ajudar?

Comment: Pra começar esqueça NSString. String é o tipo nativo do Swift. Mude o seu guard para `guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }`

Comment: Tenta usando ASCII `NSASCIIStringEncoding`

Comment: Fiz o que me disse, mas não resultou o erro persiste e é o mesmo. Mais alguma dica? Obrigado

Comment: @LeoDabus não me consegue ajudar mais? Obrigado

Comment: Não tem como te ajudar sem você saber o que voce tá perguntando

Comment: Hum, peço desculpa o que me fiz para me entender mal ou não perceber a minha dúvida. Eu penso saber qual é o problema, não sei é como resolver. Penso que o problema está na passagem dos parâmetros no método quando estou a fazer o corpo do pedido para o serviço

Comment: Tenta colocar só o método que você não sabe passar os parâmetros. Edita a sua pergunta e tenta ser mais claro e objetivo. Se a pergunta estivesse clara alguém ja teria respondido pra ganhar a reputação concorda?

Comment: Mas o método  é todo aquele que tenho postado. Pois ele faz o que tem a fazer mas na resposta do servidor vem o erro que coloquei. E é isso mesmo que não percebo. O porquê do método que coloquei dar sucesso para chamadas de métodos ao servidor (que não precisam de parametros) e dar erro nas chamada de métodos ao servidor(que precisam de parametros). Daí não dar para tirar nada do meu post inicial. Obrigado

Comment: O problema pode estar na sua url. Quando voce passa uma string (query parameter) voce precisa adicionar percent escapes antes de inicializar a sua url da uma olhada nessa resposta aqui e ve se isso te ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/a/34834294/2303865

Comment: @Leo Dabus, depois de tanta luta coloquei no meu projeto o Alamofire no entanto nos métodos em que precisam de parametros obtenho failure na comunicação. Coloquei no link seguinte o meu código pode ser que ajude [(@GabrielRodrigues, segui o teu conselho e fiz com Alamofire no entanto estou com um problema métodos em que tenha que passar parametros obtenho failure no pedido. Coloco no Link o meu código [(http://pasteboard.co/1heVRG8P.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema e a solução é a seguinte:

```
  let URL = NSURL(string: "https://****.*****.com/*****.svc/rest/GetByID")!
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let parameters = ["ID": "23"]

do {
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
} catch {
}

mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
    .responseJSON{
        response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value{

            let dataSelected = [JSON.valueForKey("Price")!]         //Quando vem apenas um objecto
            print("RESULTADO \(dataSelected)")
        }
}
```